# Deployment from Production(Enterprise) to Production(Enterprise)..?

Tags: apex, deployment, sandbox, configuration, production

Hi i have one enterprise org where there is a lot of work including VF pages,triggers,reports etc...I want to deploy all the work to a new Production(Enterprise) instance..How can i achieve this...I have deployed from one developer org to other developer org using eclipse...and also from sandbox to production..

I have less idea how to do this from production to production with different sandboxes..

Can we connect the sandbox of first production org to other production org so we can deploy..Or is there any limitation..??

Please suggest the solutions...

Is there any app on app-exchange to deploy code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make move metadata, profiles, reports, etc from one Org A to other Org B (AKA: Deploy) you have many options:

1. Eclipse
2. Migration Tool (Ant)
3. Sublime
4. Salesforce Deploy and change-sets
5. Use the medatada API and tooling API by a custom development.
6. Appexchange apps.
7. CI through Jenkins + SFDC plugins.

You only have to choose the source Org and the destiny Org. No matter if they are sandbox or production. But always have in mind test coverage and other deployment implications.

The org edition (enterprise, unlimited, etc) it is not important directly. The main concern about that should be to have the same features enabled.

I strongly recommends you to have a try of [Copado Deployer](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3dgGEAR) (on appexchange), It has a trial and you will save a lot of painful.

Last but not least read this [doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dev_lifecycle/Content/deploy.htm) to have a deeper idea of deployment if you have time.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply...Using eclipse i can deploy right..I don't want to use app-exchange app.With eclipse i can deploy everything .??

Comment: Yes, as I posted as option 1 you can deploy using Eclipse. You have some limitations, like you can only choose a destiny org, but it is ok to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Force.com IDE and ANT Migration tool.

You can find more details on the FOrce.com IDE deployment here
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Deploy_Force.com_Applications_Faster

and on ANT here
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_deploying_ant.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think Martin's list is fairly comprehensive and I think a tool like [Copado Deployer](http://www.copa.do) will probably be your best option because it's easy and quick to setup and faster than the other options that Martin listed. The tips it gives you when deployments fail are also very helpful.