# Can users send customizations from trialforce org to their production?

Tags: apex, change-set, customization, production, trialforce

Is this possible to do?

We have a user with apex customisation wanting to transfer them from trial org to production.

Change-sets didn't help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of the metadata deployment tools to do this. They don't require two orgs to be connected via Deployment settings, you just need to have access to both.

Personally, I use [Gearset](https://gearset.com/) (which has a free trial, so you could get this one-off job done for free with that).

Or you could use Force IDE, MavensMate, ANT, etc. See this question:

[Deployment from Production(Enterprise) to Production(Enterprise)..?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31454/deployment-from-productionenterprise-to-productionenterprise?rq=1)